# Question about input with scanf

Tags: c

When I execute the following program it get the user input for account details and then prints it correctly, but it cannot read the opt value (y/n). It automatically calls again. How can I get the program to exit when the user inputs "n"?

```
    char opt;
    do
{

//Getting user input

printf("\n Enter the Account Number:\n ");
scanf("%d",&gAccNo_i);                                       
printf("\n Enter the Account Holder's Name:\n ");
scanf("%s",gCustName_c);
printf("\n Enter the Balance Amount:\n ");
scanf("%f",&gBlncAmt_f);

//Printing the input data.

printf("\n Account Number     : %d",gAccNo_i);
printf("\n Customer Name      : %s",gCustName_c);
printf("\n Balance Amount     : %f",gBlncAmt_f);

printf("\n Do u want to wish to continue?(y/n)");
scanf("%c",&opt);
}while(opt!='n');
```

Comment: Is this per chance a homework assignment?

Comment: What value does `opt` have at the time you expect it to contain 'n'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `opt=getch();` inplace of `scanf("%c",&opt);`

**OR**

`scanf` reads the whitespace that is left in the buffer by previous line. To skip whitespace, add a space to the "%c":

```
scanf(" %c", &opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%c",&opt);
```

Will actually read in a space/newline character. Which obviously will not be equal to 'n'.

You may like to take the input as a string and then verify if the first character is a 'n'.

```
char opts[5];
scanf("%s",opts);
while(opts[0] !='n');
```

Comment: You might want to put a size limit in your `scanf` so that long answers will not cause buffer overflows.

Comment: @Jeremiah:How to put a size limit to scanf? Thanks.

Comment: Use `%4s` instead of `%s` for a buffer of size 5 (the string length limit does not include the trailing 0 byte, according to the `scanf` man page).